# Why is my MSbuild command path not reachable if I change my Azure DevOps agent?

Tags: c#, azure, msbuild, azure-devops, azure-devops-hosted-agent

A task of my Azure DevOps build fails to find my solution path when I change from "Hosted" Agent to "**Hosted VS2017**".

Does the folder organisation change from a agent to another ?

My C# solution used to run with .NET framework 4.6, and I reference now **4.7.1 version**. That's why I need apparently to use "Hosted VS2017" agent instead of the default "Hosted" agent.
But a task that uses a gulpfile fails when trying to build my solution. I tried to execute the build with diagnostics, but I got no more informations than "**The system cannot find the path specified.**" in my first MSbuild command.

```
---

[command]C:\npm\prefix\gulp.cmd CI-default --gulpfile D:\a\1\s\source\back-end\gulpfile.js
[‌15:41:53‌] Using gulpfile D:\a\1\s\source\back-end\gulpfile.js‌
[‌15:41:53‌] Starting &#x27;CI-default&#x27;...‌
[‌15:41:53‌] Starting &#x27;Publish-All-Projects&#x27;...‌
[‌15:41:53‌] Starting &#x27;Build-Solution&#x27;...‌
[‌15:41:53‌] Using automatic maxcpucount‌
The system cannot find the path specified.
[‌15:41:53‌] { Error: Command failed: &quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe&quot; &quot;D:\a\1\s\source\back-end\******.sln&quot; &quot;&#x2F;target:Build&quot; &#x2F;verbosity:minimal &#x2F;toolsversion:14.0 &#x2F;nologo &#x2F;maxcpucount &#x2F;property:Configuration=&quot;Release&quot;‌
The system cannot find the path specified.

 at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd:
   '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\14.0\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe" "D:\\a\\1\\s\\source\\back-end\\ALE.sln" "/target:Build" /verbosity:minimal /toolsversion:14.0 /nologo /maxcpucount /property:Configuration="Release"' }


---
```

The build fails at this steps but should execute properly (it does actually when I do it with the default "Hosted" agent or on my local machine with Visual Studio)

Comment: You haven't actually showed us the pipeline, but have you installed gulp before trying to use it?

Comment: Like I said, the build worked properly with another agent so I suppose it is installed.

Comment: Again, without showing your pipeline, I can't really help, but try installing gulp or npm install (depending on how your package.json looks like) first as a step and then run it again. Also, is your MSBuild step pointing to the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is my MSbuild command path not reachable if I change my Azure DevOps agent?

That because the Visual Studio 2015 is installed by default on the "**Hosted**" Agent, and **Hosted VS2017** with Visual Studio 2017 by default.

However, the path for the MSBuild `14.0` and `15.0` are different.

The default path for MSBuild **14.0** is `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe`.

But the default pathfor the MSBuild **15.0**, the path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe`.

So to resolve this issue, you should change the MSBuild in your CMD scripts:

```
 cmd:
   '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\14.0\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe"
```

To

```
 cmd:
   C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Enterprise\\MSBuild\\15.0\Bin\\MSBuild.exe
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it helps a lot. I just figured it out before you posted your message. I had to change my "ToolsVersions" parameter in my gulpfile from 14.0 to 15.0 and the error disappeared. Thanks though for your explanation.